# Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using the progress bar to check how many computers exist in the “COMPUTERS” container prior to moving of the computers to the specific OU “LAPTOPS. Keep in mind, when only one computer exists in the “COMPUTERS” container, I received the error message below. The computer then gets moved successfully. However, when two or more computers exist in the COMPUTER container, it did NOT project the error when moving from the container to OU. I’ve been searching to find answer but no luck. Please I need some help.

Note: I’m using Powershell version 5.1.14409.1012

[error: Does not contain method name 'op_Division'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2AEq.png)

> Method invocation failed because 
>   [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] does not contain a 
>   method named 'op_Division'.
>   At line:13 char:5
>   +     $percent = ($counter / $pcName.count) * 100
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeExcepti 
>      on
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

```
$computerCN = 'CN=COMPUTERS,DC=MYTEST,DC=LOCAL'
$pcName = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $computerCN -SearchScope OneLevel
$computerOU = 'OU=LAPTOP,OU=MYHOME,DC=MYTEST,DC=LOCAL'

$counter = 0

Foreach ( $computer in $pcName )
{

    $prefix = $computer.name
    $percent = ($counter / $pcName.count) * 100

    $counter++
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing computers' -Status "Scanning... $counter out of $($pcName.count)" -CurrentOperation $prefix -PercentComplete $percent
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

    Switch -Wildcard ( $prefix )
                        {

                            'LAP*' { 'Moved'; Get-ADComputer $computer | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $computerOU }
                            Default { 'Skip' }

                        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that GetADComputer is returning more than one object?  You should always force results of a command to a collection with the array subexpression operator when you are expecting a collection.
`$pcname = @(Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $computerCN -SearchScope OneLevel)`

Comment: I have tested and It worked perfectly. You are awesome and thank you for your help.